# IOS Swift out of range error when displaying pictures

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have data coming from Json and populating it inside a TableView . One of those elements that I am getting back from Json is a String that has a URL to an image . If a particular Json string is null or blank I get the following error

```
fatal error: Index out of range
```

Every post will not have an Image but I do not know how to tell swift to ignore a certain section of code if the String is blank . This is my code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomePageTVC", for: indexPath) as! HomePageTVC

    cell.post.text = Posts[indexPath.row]



 // Start Display Image
   // right here I get the fatal out of index if there is no image
    if profile_image_string[indexPath.row] != nil {
    let imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: profile_image_string[indexPath.row])!
    let request:NSURLRequest =  NSURLRequest(url: imgURL as URL)
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest,    completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            if data != nil {
            cell.profile_image.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
        })
    });
    task.resume()

    }
  // End Display Image   



    return cell
}
```

This is my Json being returned

```
{"post":"Check check","profile_image":null},
{"post":"check check","profile_image":"http://www.myurl.com/cats.jpg}
```

notice that if no image url exist then the default value is null . How can I check for that inside my TableView code ? Because what I am sure that is happening is that it's taking that null value and trying to convert it into an image thus I am getting the error. The value of the string URL is kept inside this string Array

```
profile_image_string[indexPath.row]
```

and this is how I append it

```
   if let profile_picture = Stream["profile_image"] as? String {
                                self.profile_image_string.append(profile_picture)
                            }
```

anyways as stated before I am successfully getting the URL String from Json and if it is a URL then the image shows, I just want to know how can I check for Nulls that way I stop getting that error any help would be great .

Comment: `profile_image_string` is having elements less than `indexPath.row`. Check what number are you returning from the `numberOfRows` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is pretty wrong

```
 if let profile_picture = Stream["profile_image"] as? String {
                                    self.profile_image_string.append(profile_picture)
                                }
```

If you want consistent array value, you have to make your `profile_image_string` can contains `nil` by make it's type `[String?]` and if the `if let` fail, append `nil` value into the array like:

```
if let....else {
   self.profile_image_string.append(nil)
}
```

Still, this way is very messy and not advised, i suggest you create proper object to hold your JSON data

Comment: Thanks will do that now